# Custom, Efficient, Complex sorting in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sorting

I would like to know how to order efficiently in Rails. We all know that you can do simple ordering in Rails with the following methods:

```
Model.order("created_at ASC").limit(10)
```

In this case I'm just pulling the first 10 entries. If I wanted to add a non-time delineated ordering I could create a column in the Model (e.g. `custom_ordering column`) and input values to order the objects. That case you would just modify the `order("custom_ordering ASC")` call.

BUT let's say I want to order based off a user's predicted preference. In this case, it's not feasible to create a new column because each user has different tastes. What would be a smart, efficient way to accomplish this task?

One method would be to create an algorithm to predict a user's rating of an object from Model called `model_rating(object)`. This algorithm would spit out a positive integer value of their rating. If I went down this path, how would I efficiently order the Model?

Another method would be to set the algorithm up as a `model_entry.user_preference(user)`. Then I could order by:

```
Model.all.sort! { |b, a| a.user_preference(user) <=> b.user_preference(user) }
```

But this strikes me as inefficient. It has to call all the entries in the model and then sort them which, even if you use efficient sorting methods like merge or bubble sort, gets poor performance on models with large numbers of entries.

Are there other paths I am not considering? Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this solution I'm assuming that the calculation of the user's preferred order is expensive and that the set that you are ordering is not updating to often.

What you could do is calculate the order every so often (in a background task) and store the calculated order in a separate table per user.

Alternatively, if you have not a lot of users, you could save in a separate table the score of each model per user, and sort by that value in a join. These values can then also be recalculated on a regular basis.

Comment: yes, these seem viable options. Do you think either of these approaches would be how a large site such as facebook orders a newsfeed? In these cases, you have both many table entries and many users.

Comment: In the case of Facebook, I think they store a separate newsfeed per person. I do not believe that the "stories" are shared between people. These stories are using shared resources (Albums, comments, etc...) but each story on your timeline is built for you. (At least, that's how I would build it)

Comment: well, very interesting! always enlightening to discuss this stuff with others! thanks very much for your input

Comment: hey - also, what about if I created a rating field and wanted to have a skew for time. How would I write an "order" method across two fields, such as popularity and created_at, and would it be efficient? I wrote a follow up question to this regard here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728287/ordering-by-a-two-fields-one-being-created-at-in-rails

Comment: I would just consider the time in your user_preference method

Comment: yeah you know, i can't believe i didn't see that. haha. Anyway, go to that question, if you want, and write that as the answer and I will gladly give you the points.

Answer (score 0):

Bubble sort is not efficient.

If you are talking about sorting a single model, then it's true that all sort input would be attributes of that model. If each user can specify their own sort preference, then it comes down to an attribute or a list of attributes. Save that list as a user preference, then dynamically construct the query. Heck, save the actual code as the preference and do an eval on it.

But, even efficient SQL breaks down when the number of records approaches a threshold. In that case, you need a new tool.

You could use a proper search implementation, which inherently includes sorting. I use Solr with the Sunspot gem. And it seems that Sphinx with the thinking-sphinx gem has good traction too.