# Ordering by a two fields, one being created_at, In Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sorting

This is a follow-up question to [Custom, Efficient, Complex Ordering in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703892/custom-efficient-complex-ordering-in-rails-3/8715275#8715275)

I'd like to develop an efficient ordering method for a rails model I have. Suppose that I save a rating for all objects in a field named "popularity". If I wanted to sort by this rating I would do:

```
  Model.order('popularity ASC')
```

How would I order by a skew for created at? Is there a way to, perhaps, convert the creation timestamp to an integer value, and then sort by popularity - created_at such that older objects' ratings decrease over time? IE something like:

```
  Model.order('popularity-integerize(created_at) ASC')
```

So: how might I do this, and is it efficient?

Comment: I would run a periodic job and decrease rating (maybe a copy of it in another column)

Comment: Not exactly related, but if you're looking for a way to run a digg/SO-style website, I would suggest looking at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions

Comment: hey - muffinista, thanks for your input, that isn't the answer per se but definitely related, and good reading! thanks. @SergioTulentsev Yes that is a possibility, I will revert to that if I can't figure out a different method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calculating your popularity, you could just keep the creation time into consideration ;)

Comment: this seems like the best way to go. simple!

Answer (score 0):

In your model, you could do something along the lines of...

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  def decaying_popularity
    popularity + created_at.to_i # created_at is larger for newer creations.
  end                            # you'll obviously need to edit the formula you use. 

  def self.order_by_decaying_popularity
    models = self.all
    models.sort {|a,b| a.decaying_popularity <=> b.decaying_popularity }
  end
end
```

When you want to call it in your controller:

```
Model.order_by_decaying_popularity
```

It should play nice with other clauses, too:

```
Model.where(:author_id => 1).order_by_decaying_popularity
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your input. Unfortunately, I feel that this is a sub-optimal solution. Won't this have to pull all the entries from the database, sorting each time? Surely that will become very slow with database growth. I am looking instead for a true order method, or an SQL joins solution. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, it will definitely pull all records. :-)

Comment: Was just playing around in the console; apparently you can sort by a formula. If you save created_at.to_i at the time of creation (maybe call it created_at_int), then you can call Model.order("popularity + created_at_int").